# keras fit time/step difference

Tags: python, keras, reinforcement-learning

Building a dqn agent, and trying to understand why calling fit in my code is orders of magnitude slower (over 1s) than another example I found (1ms). The neural nets are almost the same, the example has more connections, but that's the only difference (my alpha is set to the same as the example NN learning rate).

No idea what would cause such a difference in performance time. I thought maybe it was the way data was formatted before calling fit, but it looks like everything is the same.

My results:

[image]

Example results:

[image]

My NN:

```
q = Sequential()
q.add(Dense(24, input_dim=n_states, activation='relu'))
q.add(Dense(24, activation='relu'))
q.add(Dense(n_actions, activation='linear'))
q.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=alpha))
```

Example NN:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(32, input_dim=nS, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(nA, activation='linear'))
model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer=Adam(lr=0.01))
```

Comment: What are the values of `n_states`, `n_actions`, `nS`, and `nA`?

Comment: Also just a couple things I'd like to note: 1) Your net isn't orders of magnitude slower, it's only slower by a factor of ~2 (though that's still weird, because it looks like it should be faster). 2) Learning rate has 0 impact on how fast each iteration takes, it merely changes how much the weights are changed each iteration.

Comment: I'm using OpenAI gym, they're variable to whatever the environment is. In this case, states is 8 and actions is 4. And fair, I'm just getting into RL, figured I'd clarify since the learning rate is set in one, and a variable in the other.